# is there an exact definition in halachah of what constitutes (1)‘racism,’ or (2)discrimination?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, derabanan, oral-torah

I'm doing some work about the legal definitions of ‘racism’ as part of a wider system of legally recognised forms of ‘discrimination,’ under the UK Equity Act 2010 and later legislation. I wondered if anyone has any suggestions for precise equivalents within halachah? I’m not looking for midrashic expressions of equality of which there are many well-known examples. There are also many examples, both positive and negative of discrimination within particular aspects of halachah, but is there a guiding overall definition, other than what is popularly known as the ‘golden rule'? I appreciate many of the difficulties of comparing two different legal systems.

Comment: Check out Exodus 23:2-3